# New cats are avoiding me

Tags: cats, new-pets

So this woman lost her job and car and has become a semi-truck driver and didn't have a home for her two cats. So I rehomed them, but since they arrived four days ago, they are exploring and doing everything when I'm gone or asleep. But when I lay down in the room they're in, they actively avoid me.

Any tips on what to do? In their minds, did I take them away from a perfectly fine home and owner?

Comment: The answer to [New cat is hiding and not eating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16148/new-cat-is-hiding-and-not-eating) contains useful information, but your situation is less dramatic, so don't follow all of the advice that is given there. Your cats are not hiding, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's very normal for cats to take a while to warm up to new people, spaces, or animals. Sometimes, cats take up to a year to get to know a new human, and their behavior towards you will continue to change while that happens.

Your new adopted cats probably don't think that you took them away from something, but they likely don't understand why the change has occurred or that they can trust you.

The best strategy is to be patient. Don't chase after them, let them come to you. Go about your daily business, and say hello to them when you see them. When you have a moment, sitting quietly on or near the floor will help them view you as less of a threat and they'll be more likely to approach.

[This article](https://www.zoetispetcare.com/blog/article/bringing-new-cat-home) has several pieces of excellent advice about acclimating new cats.

Good luck!

Comment: In addition to this very good answer: try 'slow blinking'. Look at your cat and close both your eyes for half a second. This is a sign that you want to be his friend.